# how To Pass A Dynamic Value from Script to HTML In the Same Page?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, xhtml, geolocation

on one page i have Script where i can goecoder an adresse to an gps coordinates.
the script works fine.
i have on the same page a

```
<h:commandButton value="Calculer Distance"
                        action="#{intervenantControlleur.getDistance(p.latitude,latitude,p.longitude,longitude)}" />
```

the p.latitude and p.longitude are known.My problem is that i want to fill the longitude and latitude variable with the result of the script.
( the script is using to convert an adresse to longitude,latitude)
how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the values within the form with a bunch of either

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="" />
```

or

```
<h:inputHidden id="hidden" value="#{bean.hidden}" />
```

that would be populated with JavaScript either in some script of collected from JS variables in `onclick` handler of command button.

This way they will be accessible in action method with either

```
String hidden = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("hidden");
```

or simply via the bean property

```
String hidden;
```

respectively.

For `name="hidden"` stand latitude and longitude values.

Comment: thank you but i didn't get this sentence that would be populated with JavaScript either in some script of collected from JS variables in onclick handler of command button...could you plz explain more or give me a litlle example

Comment: I meant that you manipulate those values with JavaScript. You must find the way to export them.

Comment: so is not possible the action of the buton would be ManagedBean.method(); ?

Comment: It *is* possible. But do you understand the difference between server side (method parameters) and client side variables (JavaScript variables)?